# Using vb.net to fill form in Firefox

Tags: vb.net

I hope I am asking in the correct section and I need to give some background info first

I started using Visual studio and vb.net in 2005 and have upgraded Visual studio and my desktop programs many times since then

I currently use Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit)
I have maybe 30+ vb.net programs for windows desktop and personal use only

One of my vb.net programs accesses Quickbooks 2022 via the QB SDK
I can import orders directly from my shopping cart into QB
From QB, I can then pull the customer name address info and then import that shipping info into Stamps.com to create shipping labels. No hand typing of anything which is very fast

I recently discontinued processing credit cards in QB (Intuit) because of their thieving money grabbing practices. They wanted $550 for one year of processing credit card sales

So I went to PayPal and they set me up in less that 15 minutes because I am a PayPal developer.
I now process credit cards in PayPal via a virtual terminal on a web page

I also set up Bank of America virtual terminal processing, but PayPal is way easier.

I set up a button in my program to open Firefox and go to the PayPal virtual terminal web page using  Process.Start(webAddress)

But of course that only opens the web page and I have to hand type all the customer data that I pulled from QB.

I want to take that QB data and fill the PayPal form out in Firefox but I am unclear how to do that on an external browser like Firefox. (Webbrowser in vb.net is no good for this application)

I am not an expert programmer and have not found anything by doing many searches.
My question is this.
Can anyone point me to a vb.net example on how to open Firefox in vb.net and then fill out a form using the data I already have?
Thanks you for any information

Tried to open Firefox in external browser

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.